Super+² "switch windows of an application" broken in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I only install LTS ubuntu versions, so this might not have started in 24.04, possibly in 23.
On my system, the Super+² keyboard shortcut does not work any more.
When using this combination on "passive" windows, all is fine.
Now, when using this while a window with a text input is active, then the shortcut has no effect, and a "²" is simply written in the text input.
So, if you are typing a mail, text doc, or code, then you cannot switch between windows any more.
Am I the only one to see this?
If I want to report a bug, which part of ubuntu does this affect, where would I report this? Thanks!
